# MATLAB vs Python numpy array/matrix multiplication

Tags: arrays, matlab, numpy, matrix, dot-product

I am translating some MATLAB code and am having some problems understanding the syntaxical difference between MATLAB and numpy for Python.

In MATLAB I have a 6 by 6 matrix, A, as well as 6 float values, a, b, c, d, e, f.
The MATLAB code

```
B = A*[a;b;c;d;e;f];
```

produces a 6 by 1 matrix, B.
So I figured that the MATLAB operator '*' must correspond to the numpy operator numpy.dot().

So in my Python code I have the same matrix, A, and the same values for a, b, c, d, e and f.

```
B = numpy.dot(A, [[a],[b],[c],[d],[e],[f]])
```

does not produce the same matrix, B, and neither does

```
B = numpy.dot(A, [a,b,c,d,e,f])
```

I have also tried building the Python matrix and array with numpy's array function with the same result.
It feels like I am mixing something fundamental up here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Matlab `[a;b;c;d;e;f]` is a column vector, are you sure your numpy vectors are column vectors and not row vectors?

Comment: Do you have a numpy matrix or an array? http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935

Comment: Also, you will get a much better response if you explain what the difference is between what you expected and what you got instead of making people guess!

Comment: @Dan Yes, my numpy vector is a column vector. And yes, I use numpy's array() method for creating my matrices and arrays.

Comment: In Matlab, if `A` is 6 by 6, `A*[a;b;c;d;e;f]` should be 6 by 1 (i.e. a column vector).  Are you sure you got a 1 x 6 matrix?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Sorry, yes I got a 6 by 1 vector. Will edit the question.

Comment: Please include code in your question that we can run (i.e. include the code that defines `A`, `a`, `b`, etc), and show the output that you get in Matlab and python.

Comment: If the Python `B` was also `(6,1)`, what was wrong, or different?

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer fully without knowing the values in `A`, and `a,b,c,d,e,f`. However, you're code seems to work:

MATLAB:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6;
     1,2,3,4,5,6;
     1,2,3,4,5,6;
     1,2,3,4,5,6;
     1,2,3,4,5,6;
     1,2,3,4,5,6];

b = [7;8;9;10;11;12];

A*b

ans = 

  217
  217
  217
  217
  217
  217

A'*b

ans = 

   57
  114
  171
  228
  285
  342
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6],
              [1,2,3,4,5,6]])

b = np.array([7,8,9,10,11,12]).reshape(6, 1)

B = np.dot(A, b)

B
array([[217],
       [217],
       [217],
       [217],
       [217],
       [217]])

B = np.dot(A.transpose(), b)

B
array([[57],
       [114],
       [171],
       [228],
       [285],
       [342]])
```

The numpy `dot` operator does perform matrix multiplication, so it is likely that something is going wrong with your initialisation of `A` which you don't show.

Note that the `reshape` operation is not necessary (the same results are seen regardless). However, this makes a column vector rather than a 1D array and so can be transposed etc. in the same fashion as the MATLAB array `[7;8;9;10;11;12]`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser True, I've changed it to a reshape. It's not necessary but it makes the point that this is a column vector which matches the equivalent MATLAB code that was posted (and follows the matrix multiplication rules). I'll also add a note explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

The vector you are multiplying is a column, so use it as a column to have a final 6x1 vector and not a 1x6 vector, as you are doing a dot product of 6x6 by 6x1 in MATLAB.

This example is for a 3x3 dimension (just to reduce the code and be understandable):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[8,1,6],[3,5,7],[4,9,2]])  # This is the matrix
b = np.array([1,2,3])                    # These are the float numbers
c = np.dot(A,b.reshape(-1,1))            # This is a 3x1 vector
```

This is equivalent on MATLAB to:

```
magic(3)*[1;2;3]
```